# Rotated text glitchy in safari during sibling animation

Tags: css

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/vanechka222/pen/QWgEWOm?editors=1100)

I have this structure

```css
body {
  background-color: #1e1f26;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.card {
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(#000, 0.5);
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
 }
.card .description {
        background-color: rgba(#fff, 0.5);
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(10%);
}

.card:hover .description {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
  
.card .label {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 15%;
        right: -30%;
        background: #f31;
  }
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="description">
    Lalala
  </div>
  <div class="label">
    LABEL
  </div>
</div>
```

Label is rotated -45 deg

Description has `opacity: 0` by default, but on hover is shown

This works perfectly fine in chrome, butt in safari label text gets glitchy or somewhat blurry during the description transition.

What can cause this? Is there a fix?

Comment: Try `z-index: 1;` on rotating div and/or `transform: translateZ(0);` to parent container (see [many answers on web](https://www.google.com/search?q=safari+glich+rotate+css)).

Comment: That didn't help

Comment: Safari is these days much like Internet Explorer long time ago, sorry about your case, feel no sorry for it :)